# HTML for a PHP function

Tags: php, html, sql

I used prepared statements for my data collection. I am trying to display that data with a fetch_array function in an organized fashion. Is it possible to insert an html table into a php function that relies on a prepared statement?

I've read to use a HEREDOC, but I do not know what to do in place of the variables. I've also tried to create another document for a table, but have the same question.

This is the function I am using.

```
function showProfile($user) {
    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'";

    $result = $connection->query($query);
    /* associative array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    printf(
        "%s <br> %s\n",
        $row["forename"],
        $row["surname"]
    ) . "<br style='clear:left;'><br>";
}
```

This is the table I want to use

```
<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2">Your Profile Information </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $forename ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?php echo $surname ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can display my data with the function, however, I want to display it in a more organized way.

Comment: I do not see you using prepared statements. You are still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: The prepared statements are from another file. The function just fetches the data from the database and is part of a functions file. Should I still be concerned about injection? I haven't tried Johanne's answer, but JeffCasino's answer worked fine.

Comment: Yes always use prepared statements. Never put PHP variables into SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

instead of printf(), you can just echo

```
echo "<table width='398'> <-- check here the quote marks so the string doesnt break
  <tr>
    <td>".$row['forename']."</td> <- then concat all the variables you want like this
  </tr>
</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but this function but it should work.  I have wrapped the table rows, in a while loop, although it may not be necessary if you are getting back one row in your query.

```
   function showProfile($user)
    {
        global $connection;

        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user = :user ");
        $query->bindValue(':user', $user);

        $result =  $query->execute();

        echo "<table width='398' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0'>
                  <tr><td height='26' colspan='2'>Your Profile Information </td>
                  </tr> ";

        /* associative array */  
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "
                  <tr>
                      <td width='82' valign='top'><div align='left'>FirstName:</div></td>
                      <td width='165' valign='top'>{$row['forename']}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td valign='top'><div align='left'>LastName:</div></td>
                      <td valign='top'>{$row['surname']}</td>
                   </tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: This code is for a user that is logged in, and displaying their data, if someone can get into an area for a logged in user, then there is more to worry about that sql injection... further more, from this example, we do not know if the $user variable has been escaped before been passed to the function.  Finally, with a query like this: "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user= '$user' "; show me a query that can be passed in the user variable that will not throw an error.... "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user= ' DROP TABLE;' ";

Comment: I mean.. if the login is also open to SQL injection then .... which, based on this.. is. Why promote further use and instead promote a better usage throughout the project?

Comment: I have edited the code to include prepared statements... it is still untested.

Comment: @Johanne Do not try to advocate for bad programming practices. **NEVER** put PHP variables inside of SQL queries, unless they have been white listed. Escaping does not prevent SQL injection, neither does authorization. The only thing which prevents SQL injections is prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks.  I always use prepared statements in my own code, so I guess I should encourage others to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

As much as possible, you want to separate logic from presentation.  Your table example is definitely on track. However, I would suggest thinking a little differently about the output of the function. Instead of the function returning HTML, have it return data that a view could use.

An object is much better suited for the task than a single function:

```
<?php
class Profile {
  private $conn;
  private $result;

  public function __construct($conn) {
    $this->conn = $conn;
  }

  public function findProfile($user) {
    $query = “SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user=?”;

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(‘s’, $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->result = $stmt->get_result();
  }

  public function fetch() {
    //if($row = $this->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc()) {
      return $row;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then your table can be separated into its own file, to be included whenever you wish (assuming $conn and $user are defined):

```
<?php
$p = new Profile($conn);
$p->findProfile($user);
?>

<!— html stuff here —>
<?php if($info = $p->fetch()): ?>
<table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="26" colspan="2">Your Profile Information </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">FirstName:</div></td>
    <td width="165" valign="top"><?= $info[‘forename’] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left">LastName:</div></td>
    <td valign="top"><?= $info[‘surname’] ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I read somewhere keeping these separate is a golden rule. I am however, receiving a fatal error with $q or bindValue(). "Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object". Does this have to do with my connection or some other variable?

Comment: TBH, I don’t use mysqli or pdo on a regular basis (I use a custom abstraction), so my code could be wonky. Which are you using, mysqli or pdo?

Comment: I have been using mysqli.

Comment: I’ll have to look at mysqli docs. The error is saying that $q is not an object, so perhaps $conn is not what I expected.

Comment: my fault. I did not clarify in my question.

Comment: This should work better, however, the docs show closing the statement and the connection. You may need to add a method to do that, IDK.  Mysqli is a weird looking beast...